# Существует ли в DevExpress метод редактирования данных наподобие EhLibовских DropDownForm?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

[image: Поле с данными можно редактировать/добавлять/удалять, а не только выбирать из уже существующих значений.]
Поле с данными можно редактировать/добавлять/удалять, а не только выбирать из уже существующих значений.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать: `TcxPopupEdit`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Данный класс (компонент) обладает всеми необходимыми параметрами для реализации требуемого функционала с минимальными затратами.